# Can we use Business Objects which we made & data acess Layer of LINQ?

Tags: linq

Can we use Business Objects which we made & data acess Layer of LINQ?

Because i want to put the validation in Business Objects & also want to use data acess Layer of Linq?

Comment: Are you talking about LINQ to SQL, or LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should read [This](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=476) article written by Imar Spaanjaars. It explains very well how to use the DAL (Data Acces Layer) and validation together with LINQ in layered structures. Basically he says to create a different validation layer which validates your objects before sending them to the DAL. I hope it helps you

Comment: He does not use DAL created by dragging all tables in Linq to sql Class